Remove the prompts that has been added by WhatsApp
When creating a sticker and sending it to a sticker pack that has been added to WhatsApp, this prompt appears: sticker pack name has bean already added to WhatsApp. I want to remove this prompt. What should I do?
I tried intent.putExtra("image_data_version", version) but nothing works

Your question is extremely unclear. Please give some context as well as a [mre] so readers can run your code and reproduce your issue. Please also tag the programming language you're using.
